# Reusable/extensible deisgn of toggle to be used for switching dark mode on/off

Tags: html, css, gui

I though of defining the following module that I could use to govern the dark mode on/off on a website.

Probably I would use it only for that in the whole page, but in the case I don't (i.e. I end up wanting to use it in other places), I'd like to be sure it's reusable enough.

I tried to make it geometrically consistent by defining 3 independent variables, `--track-height`, `--track-AR` (AR = aspect ratio), and `--thumb-diameter-to-track-height`, and then defining all the others in terms of those. This should make, if I understand correctly, the geometry of the tool independed from where it's included.

What worries me are the colors, which I *have* hardcoded. On the other hand, if I truly use this toggle to switch dark mode on/off, then it *must* trigger its own recoloring, so in principle its colors should't be hardcoded but come higher in the hierarchy.

```css
input.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-left: -1000px;
}

input.toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.toggle+label {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #999999;
  --track-height: 1em;
  --track-AR: 2.2;
  --thumb-diameter-to-track-height: 1.3;
  --track-width: calc(var(--track-AR) * var(--track-height));
  height: var(--track-height);
  width: var(--track-width);
  border-radius: calc(0.5 * var(--track-height));
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0.08em 0.08em 0.2em #333;
}

input.toggle+label::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

input.toggle+label::after {
  --thumb-diameter: calc(var(--thumb-diameter-to-track-height) * var(--track-height));
  height: calc(var(--thumb-diameter));
  width: calc(var(--thumb-diameter));
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #555555;
  position: absolute;
  --leftover: calc(0.5 * (var(--thumb-diameter) - var(--track-height)));
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--leftover));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--leftover));
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background-image: radial-gradient(2em at 25% 25%, white, #555 60%, black);
  box-shadow: 0.08em 0.08em 0.2em #333;
}

input.toggle:checked+label::after {
  left: calc(var(--track-width) - var(--thumb-diameter) + var(--leftover));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="toggle" class="toggle" type="checkbox" value="" />
  <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```